VBA to find header on one sheet, and Copy the information to another sheet
I have a what I would think is simple, but having some troubles
I have some code that I want to modify.  I would like it to look at "ActiveSheet" for a specific Header ("Order No"), then copy all information below that header and past it into my destination sheet2 A2:A400.  This is my code right now.  Please let me know where I can start
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()

Core.TurnOffSettings

Dim NewWB As Workbook
Dim Path As String
Path = UserSelectFile("Only Select a RAW copy of the WO report from Apriso" & vbCr & "If you change any lines this process will not work", "Report Select:", 0)
Set NewWB = TransferData2NewBook(Path)
x = FindLastRowSht(ActiveSheet)

Sheet2.Range("A2:AC" & x).ClearContents

x = FindLastRowSht(ActiveSheet)

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:AC" & x).Offset(0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A2:AC" & x).Offset(0)

NewWB.Close False

Core.ResetSettings

With Sheet2.Range("A2:A500")
 .NumberFormat = "0"
 .Value = .Value
End With

Sheet3.Range("W6").Value = Now

Sheets("Dashboard").Select


End Sub

I have looked on line for many ideas, but some seem more complicated that I think it should be.


Using Find method to locate the header

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Find method (Excel)


Range.Copy method (Excel)

Option Explicit
Sub CopyCol()
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' ActiveSheet , source sheet, modify as needed
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2") ' dest sheet, modify as needed
    Dim c As Range, lastC As Range
    ' locate the header
    Set c = oSht1.Cells.Find("Order No", Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        ' get the last non-blank cell within the column
        Set lastC = oSht1.Cells(oSht1.Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp)
        ' copy to dest sheet
        oSht1.Range(c.Offset(1), lastC).Copy oSht2.Range("A2")
    End If
End Sub



You beat me to typing it (i was doing a walkthrough of what each line means)!  My only critique is the call out of "activesheet" in the post, where more sheets may exist for other orders, and I was going to ensure the sheet was not sheet2.
